# Why is save_post hook being called twice despite all my efforts?

Tags: hooks

I understand that `save_post` hook can fire various times, based on autosaving, revisions, etc.

With that in mind, I have a `save_post` hook set up as

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'do_stuff', 5000, 2 );
function do_stuff($post_id, $post) {
```

At the start of the function I have

```
    if (isset($post->post_status) && 'auto-draft' == $post->post_status) {
        return;
    }

    // Autosave, do nothing
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    // AJAX? Not used here
    if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) {
        return;
    }

    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) return;
```

I thought this would ensure one call to the hook. But upon hitting Update on a post edit, I see from some logging that I am doing that the hook is called twice.

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I have a custom Gutenberg block plugin I am using to extend a core block? In my plugin php file I don't have anything other than loading of the plugin's js. So I am not sure how the plugin would play a role here.

In any case, just curious if I am missing something obvious...

Thanks

Comment: How are you logging/testing this theory? Why does it matter that it runs twice? What is the problem that this solves?

Comment: I just use the write_log function to see when it is being called. In save hooks, I sometimes do various database manipulations, or interact with some service like Mailchimp, and really don't want to be re-running actions that I only want to do once.

Comment: how do you know that it's the same request though? That hook may not be the ideal place to do those things as it could significantly slow down saving. Also, if a user clicks update, then immediately updates again, you'll get the same problem but triggered by a human. If you only want something to happen once, you need to make sure it sets a flag or a note somewhere saying that it's happened so that the next time it sees that flag and doesn't do it again. Are you sure these are things you want to happen on post save and not post publish?

Comment: The types of things I am saving are things like a webinar start date. I might not have that field filled out at publish time. Later if I update and set that field, I trigger an api call to Zoom to set up corresponding data in Zoom. The hook is save_post_myposttype, I see it called twice, but haven't done backtrace to see how it is being called twice. I thought about setting flag somewhere so that I exit, but was trying to avoid that, and instead rely on some hook that I can rely on running once.

Comment: you can switch from save_post to a specific status transition, but I don't believe you can use hooks to differentiate between quick successive save requests and ones that are hours or days apart, they're all classed as post updates. If they're on separate requests then trying to use variables wouldn't help. You could try and optimise it by comparing the old meta to the new meta and only making requests to zoom if the values are different but that'd be a different question and I don't remember the specifics off the top of my head

Comment: as for debugging, saving and using the network panel should reveal if it's two requests or one request, query monitor might be able to help as well

Answer (score 2):

`save_post` becomes unwieldy under Gutenberg, in my experience. It fires at least twice, and none of the checks you have in place will distinguish between instances.

I would consider replacing it with [`wp_after_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_after_insert_post/), which was introduced into core for this very reason.

Comment: Some plugins incorrectly make a second REST API request to save meta after a post has been saved because the author doesn't understand the core data API and doesn't realise Gutenberg will send the meta for them if they register it and update the posts meta directly. This is where that comes from, and it's bad practice

Comment: Ok, thanks, will give that a try.

Comment: @Brian did this answer your question? If it did, can you consider marking it as the accepted answer?